# How can I make an image overflow an Android screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a decorative image that runs along the bottom of the view. It does not have any repeating elements. I want this long image to fill the bottom edge of the view in both portrait and landscape, taking up the same vertical space in both. Essentially, I need the image anchored to the bottom left and overflowing the screen on the bottom right. What I've tried so far (example below) actually fits the horizontal extents of the image to the screen edges and compresses the height in accordance with the aspect ratio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- more... -->
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:scaleType="fitEnd"
               android:background="#ff0000"
               android:src="@drawable/foreground" />
    <!-- more... -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I anchor the image to the left and overflow the screen to the right?